# Using GridSpec with custom wspace doesn't work with tight_layout

Tags: matplotlib

The final goal I'm trying to achieve here is to have a figure saved as a .pdf with a certain size (`[5,2]` in the example code below), with no padding outside the axis labels/tick labels.

I usually achieve this by creating a figure using a combination of `figsize` and setting the padding to zero via `tight_layout` (I added the grey background color to show the edges/padding better):

```
fig = plt.figure(
    figsize = [5,2],
    tight_layout = {'pad': 0}
)

t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s = 1 + np.sin(2*np.pi*t)
plt.plot(t, s)

plt.savefig('figure.pdf', facecolor = (0.7,0.7,0.7))
```

This creates a nice pdf with size 5x2.

[image]

But I'm having trouble doing this with a figure where I'm using GridSpec to create subplots. The strange thing is that the problem is only apparent when setting a custom `wspace` for the GridSpec.

#### Example without wspace

```
fig, (ax0, ax1) = plt.subplots(
    nrows = 1, ncols = 2,
    gridspec_kw = {'width_ratios' : [3,2]},
    tight_layout = {'pad': 0},
    figsize = [5,2]
)

t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s = 1 + np.sin(2*np.pi*t)
ax0.plot(t, s)
ax1.plot(t, s)

ax1.yaxis.tick_right()

ax0.set_xlim([0, 2.25])
ax1.set_xlim([-0.25, 2])

plt.savefig('figure.pdf')
```

[image]

#### Example *with* wspace

I add some wspace to have some space between the subplots, since they are so close together in the example above

```
fig, (ax0, ax1) = plt.subplots(
    nrows = 1, ncols = 2,
    gridspec_kw = {'width_ratios' : [3,2], 'wspace' : 0.1},
    tight_layout = {'pad': 0},
    figsize = [5,2]
)

t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s = 1 + np.sin(2*np.pi*t)
ax0.plot(t, s)
ax1.plot(t, s)

ax1.yaxis.tick_right()

ax0.set_xlim([0, 2.25])
ax1.set_xlim([-0.25, 2])

plt.savefig('figure.pdf', facecolor = (0.7,0.7,0.7))
```

(the only change from above is the added `wspace` to the `gridspec_kw` dict)

This gives me an error in the `savefig` command

```
C:\Users\<username>\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py:1744:
UserWarning: This figure includes Axes that are not compatible with
tight_layout, so its results might be incorrect.
  warnings.warn("This figure includes Axes that are not "
# the warning is cut off here for some reason
```

and produces the following image, clearly not using `tight_layout`

[image]

Does anyone know of a way to get around this issue, or a better way to do what I'm trying?

Answer (score 0):

If the aim is to save the image, you may leave out the tight_layout argument to the figure, and use  the arguments `bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0` when savng the figure:

```
plt.savefig('figure.pdf', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)
```

Comment: But doesn't it change the figsize by cropping the excessive margins?